# Webcontrol firing OnLoad but not OnPreRender

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-controls

I'm currently new to a system and working on a particular bug.  A User Control (.ascx) is not being sent to the client.  When I traced the execution, OnLoad of the ascx was firing, but when I checked OnPreRender, it is not.

I am wondering what could be possible causes?  I've tried a lot of things, but this has left me stumped.

Comment: Is your control included in the Form.Controls collection?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because AutoEventWireup is not set to true in the user control page directive?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPreRender(e);
}
```